# Data not getting inserted in database app android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database app. In this app I insert data internally. But it seems that data is not getting inserted. My helper class is----

```
public class ThirdHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public ThirdHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String CREATE_TABLE=  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + MATH+ " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DSA+ " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DEC+ " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + WT+ " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DMS+" INTEGER NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

        insertData(4,4,3,4,4);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    }

    public void insertData(Integer math,Integer dsa,Integer dec,Integer wt,Integer dms)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(MATH,math);
        values.put(DSA,dsa);
        values.put(DEC,dec);
        values.put(WT,wt);
        values.put(DMS,dms);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);

        db.close();
    }
```

In my activity  class cursor is as follows--

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{_ID,MATH, DSA, DEC, WT, DMS}, null, null, null, null, null);


                if (c!=null) {
                    c.moveToFirst();
                   while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
                        math = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MATH));
                        dsa = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DSA));
                        dec = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DEC));
                        wt = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(WT));
                        dms = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DMS));
                    }
                }

               double d = ((mathInt / 10 + 1) * math + (dsaInt / 10 + 1) * dsa + (decInt / 10 + 1) * dec + (wtInt / 10 + 1) * wt + (dmsInt / 10 + 1) * dms);
```

It seems that getInt() returns 0.That is why value of double 'd' shows 0 in text view.Why this happens? Am I doing some wrong in taking input?

Comment: Tried breakpoint and debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: Are you sure that your db object is valid when executing the db.query()? Can you try to remove `db.close()` in `insertData` method?

Comment: ThirdHelper helper = new ThirdHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: after removing db.close() in insertData method problem still remains.

Comment: It's hard to tell where the issue is. You can use sqlite3 (i am assuming your using an sqllite3 database) command line tool to open your database file and investigate/modify the table content. If your happy with the database you can continue on investigating the java programme. Maybe you need db.commit() after inserting the data. (Sorry that this is all vague)